# Excel chart axis does not depict the data correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a problem with an Excel chart.

I have

- a primary axis (two series), showing volumes in millions
- a secondary axis showing percentages (one series)

The primary axis seems to be adding the two series together and then posting an equivalent whole number of the total as the maximum. If you also look at the chart, the lesser volume series is appearing above the bigger volume series.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It is going to be hard to help with this without access to the spreadsheet or more detail about what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

Without any additional info (like Paul mentioned), I'd check two things:

For the adding the two series together-that sounds like you've used a stacked chart as opposed to a standard chart (column, I'm guessing).  Try changing the chart type to a clustered column chart and see if that fixes your first problem.

As for the series order, select one of your series, right-click and choose select data.  From that dialog box, try moving the top series down and see if that fixes your order issue.  This is the dialog box equivalent of changing the series order (last number) in the =Series formula.